# Why am I getting an error message about "unexpected non-whitespace after JSON data"

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

Can anybody tell me what the problem is with this:

I am echoing out a PHP array into javascript as follows:

```
<?php 
    $myArray=array();
    foreach ($persons as $person) {
    array_push($myArray,$person['id']);
    }
?>

$(document).ready(function() {
    populatePersons(JSON.parse(<?php echo json_encode($myArray);?>));
});
```

So basically I am echo'ing out a PHP array in [json](/questions/tagged/json) format, and then parsing it in [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) but I am getting this error in my console log:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data
```

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: And what happens if you do `echo trim(json_encode($myArray));` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?

While `json_encode` produces JSON, you are `echo`ing it into JavaScript. As such it will be interpreted as a JavaScript array literal, not a string containing JSON. Hence you cannot use `JSON.parse`.

Just get rid of it:

```
populatePersons(<?php echo json_encode($myArray);?>);
```

---

If you looked at the generated code, you would something like:

```
 populatePersons(JSON.parse([1,2,3]));
```

But `JSON.parse` expects a **string** (containing JSON). Because JavaScript performs type conversion, it will convert the array to a string first, which likely does not result in valid JSON.

Again: You already have an array, there is no need to parse anything.

Answer (score 1):

Its because youre feeding JSON.parse an array. Just get rid of the JSON.prase in your javascript and replace it with JSON.stringify if youre trying to display the json. If not, then json_encode($myArray) should be enough for operations.

```
<div id = 'test'></div>

<script>
    var test = document.getElementById('test');
    test.innerHTML  =  JSON.stringify(<?php echo json_encode($myArray)?>);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the json_encode string in quotes.

```
populatePersons(JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($myArray);?>'));
```

As the parameter expected is string.